# Python Chained get() Method With List Element inside JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

[Python 2.7]

I have a JSON source that doesn't always return the full list of expected keys. I'm using chained gets() to address this.

```
d = {'a': {'b': 1}}

print(d.get('a', {}).get('b', 'NA'))
print(d.get('a', {}).get('c', 'NA'))

>>> 1
>>> NA
```

However, some dicts are in a list:

```
d = {'a': {'b': [{'c': 2}]}}

print(d['a']['b'][0]['c'])

>>> 2
```

I can't use a get() method to account for this because lists don't support the get() attribute:

```
d.get('a', {}).get('b', []).get('c', 'NA')

>>> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Beyond trapping the hundreds of potential KeyErrors, is there a preferred method to account for the potential missing `['c']` (in similar fashion to the chained get() construct above)?

Comment: `.get('b', [{}])[0]`, maybe?

Comment: _"Beyond trapping the hundreds of potential KeyErrors, [...]"_ What's wrong with a `try: ... except:`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks.  That is what I was looking for.  Please consider adding this as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Rawing: Answered in the OP.  I want to avoid having to use hundreds of try blocks. I tried a single try with a recursion, but given the complexity of the source, it became too unwieldy.

Comment: I don't see why you would need more than one `try` block. Write a function to retrieve the dict/list item you want, and if that throws an exception, return a default value.

Comment: I'm pulling hundreds of values from the dict. If I use a single `try`, I lose all the key/value pairs that haven't been assigned at the point where the exception is encountered. I want to get as many as possible. I tried to get at this with a recursion, but couldn't land on anything that seemed to work given the nature of the dict. `get()` does this well for "pure" dicts, but doesn't work when lists are involved.

Comment: That's why I said "write a function". Instead of a hundred `try` blocks you'll have 100 function calls. And `result = lookup(d, ['a','b'])` is arguably nicer than `result = d.get('a', {}).get('b')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @stovfl that writing your own lookup function is the way to go. Although, I don't think a recursive implementation is necessary. The following should work well enough:

```
def nested_lookup(obj, keys, default='NA'):
    current = obj
    for key in keys:
        current = current if isinstance(current, list) else [current]
        try:
            current = next(sub[key] for sub in current if key in sub)
        except StopIteration:
            return default
    return current


d = {'a': {'b': [{'c': 2}, {'d': 3}]}}

print nested_lookup(d, ('a', 'b', 'c'))  # 2
print nested_lookup(d, ('a', 'b', 'd'))  # 3
print nested_lookup(d, ('a', 'c'))       # NA
```

The class approach doesn't seem great because you're going to be creating a lot of unnecessary objects and if you're ever trying to lookup a node that isn't a leaf, then you're going to wind up with a custom object rather than the actual node object.

Comment: Thank you for this. It works well and seems straightforward.  I am going to accept this answer even though @stovfl's second example also works well. I was unable to come up with a satisfactory function on my own and thus unable to implement the suggestion that Rawing was making to move it to a function.

Answer (score 3):

> **Question**: I can't use a get() ... because lists don't support the get().

1. You can implement your own `list.get()`, for instance:

   ```
   class myGET(object):
       def __init__(self, data):
           if isinstance(data, dict):
               self.__dict__.update(data)
           if isinstance(data, list):
               for d in data:
                   self.__dict__.update(d)

       def get(self, key, default=None):
           if hasattr(self, key):
               _attr = object.__getattribute__(self, key)
               if isinstance(_attr, (list, dict)):
                   return myGET(_attr)
               else:
                   return _attr
           else:
               return default

   d = {'a': {'b': [{'c': 2}]}}
   myGET(d).get('a', {}).get('b', []).get('c', 'NA')
   >>> 2

   myGET(d).get('a', {}).get('b', []).get('d', 'NA')
   >>> NA
   ```
2. A *recursive* Solution, no need to *chaining*, for instance:

   ```
   def get(_dict, subkey, default):
       def _get(_dict, key, deep):
           if key == subkey[deep]:
               if deep == len(subkey) - 1:
                   return _dict
               else:
                   return _get(_dict, None, deep + 1)

           elif isinstance(_dict, dict):
               for k in _dict:
                   match = _get(_dict[k], k, deep)
                   if match: return match

           elif isinstance(_dict, list):
               for e in _dict:
                   match = _get(e, None, deep)
                   if match: return match

       if not isinstance(subkey, (tuple, list)):
           subkey = (subkey)

       _r = _get(_dict, None, 0)
       if not _r: return default
       else:      return _r

   get(d, 'c', 'NA')
   >>> 2

   get(d, 'd', 'NA')
   >>> NA

   # get a inside b
   d = {'a': {'b': [{'a': 3}, {'c': 2}]}}
   get(d, ('b', 'a'), 'NA')
   >>> 3
   ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Comment: Thank you for this.  Your first example gives me an exception, but the second one works well.  The error (Python 2 vs 3?):  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled text 21", line 23, in <module>
    myGET(d).get('a', {}).get('b', []).get('c', 'NA')
  File "untitled text 21", line 14, in get
    _attr = object.__getattribute__(self, key)
AttributeError: 'instance' object has no attribute 'a'`

Comment: @DaveL17: Yes a 2.7 Issue, missing Subclass `class myGET(object):`, fixed.