# Python parsing JSON with potential missing fields

Tags: python, json, facebook, dictionary, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently working with Python and Facebook Graph API.

I need to parse the information that I retrieve from the Facebook Graph API, and I was wondering about which would be the best way to do this.

Certainly,

```
r = json.loads(request)
```

Would parse the JSON and generate a dictionary.

The problem comes when I need to access nested dictionaries, for example

```
ob["data"][0]["reactions"]["data"][0]
```

Supposing we are parsing Facebook Posts, if the post has no reactions, of course this will miserably fail, since that key won't even exist in the dictionary.

```
if 'comments' not in dct and 'summary' not in dct and 'total_count' not in dct:
    dct["comments"] = {"summary": {"total_count": -1}}
```

As a temporary solution I ended up doing things like these, to create "Default values" so the schema would never break, and be able to read any node in the graph without getting an error.

What do you guys think? How could this be done better?

EDIT:

```
  class post(DynamicDocument):
        def __init__(self, *dct, **tmp):
            Document.__init__(self, **tmp)
            if dct:
                ....
                self.totalComentarios = dct["comments"]["summary"]["total_count"]
```

Comment: use `d.get(desc, default value)`.  Perhaps you could add some sample JSON to make the application of this solution more clear.

Comment: Just wrap it in a `try` block and catch the KeyError/IndexError?

Comment: The thing is I have something like this :
 *CHECK EDIT ON POST*

and having dct.get("comments", {}") would not be enough, I would need to do this for every level, so also for summary, and total count in this case, but there are deeper cases.

Comment: Use this Approach: [ Chained get() Method ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45077397/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

You just want to use safe accessors for each level of access.  It can't be a one liner, but that's okay:

```
data = ob.get('data', [])
entry = data[0] if len(data) else {}
reactions = entry.get('reactions', {})
reaction_data = reactions.get('data', [])
...
```

The `entry = data[0] if len(data) ...` may not be necessary if you are iterating over each entry, but a decent example of how to make iterative development not fail.

Comment: Yes but I feel this is a pain, was wondering if there's a better way, checking one by one is gonna take me a while

Comment: Well that's the problem with weakly-typed data structures like this JSON data.  There isn't a lot you can do if the data comes back with a different schema each time.  You can construct a custom class that knows how to handle missing keys and then access the members of that class easily, but again, you have to do safe checking of each part of the JSON object along the way.